Why is this XPath invalid?
To the honorable people of stackoverflow:
I'm trying to identify element via visible text using the following XPath:
//*[contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textOne')][not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textOne')])][contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textTwo')][not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textTwo')])]

It works fine in Chrome. But yields InvalidSelectorException with Selenium.
I asked a similar question here but this seems to have a different cause.
What is wrong with the expression?
I tried
//*[contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textOne')][not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textOne')])][contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textTwo')][not(.//*[contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textTwo')])]

I was expecting it to identify the element but resulted in exception.

Not directly relevant, but I'm pretty sure that [contains(normalize-space(string()), 'textTwo')] can be reduced to [contains(., 'textTwo')]

should "string()" be "text()"?  (text() is a method you can use on an element to get the displayed text  of a text node)  As is I think you're getting a bool or primitive object back?

Because there is an extra ] at the end.  Delete it, and your XPath will be syntactically valid.
Update per OP's comment

The extra brackets were mistakenly included in the question. I removed the brackets from the question. The error persists even without the extra brackets.

Without the extra ] at the end of the XPath expression, it it syntactically valid.  If you are still getting an InvalidSelectorException exception with this corrected expression, then your XPath processor is limited/defective.

I'm trying to identify multiple elements on page and executing it via Executor Service (multiple threads) it possible for there to be some conflict between simultaneously executed findElements() which would result in above exception?

InvalidSelectorException indicates a syntax error.  If you're asking whether a non-thread-safe XPath processor could behave unpredictably when run in a multithreaded environment, sure, possibly.

Thanks for your reply. The extra brackets were mistakenly included in the question. I removed the brackets from the question. The error persists even without the extra brackets. I'm trying to identify multiple elements on page and executing it via Executor Service (multiple threads) it possible for there to be some conflict between simultaneously executed findElements() which would result in above exception?

The XPath expression in your question is syntactically valid. It's hard to say what your problem is, but I suspect the bug is not in the XPath but in the code which invokes the XPath expression. However, unless you post actual code, and actual sample data, there's no way anyone can replicate your problem. Please take the time to read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
You also haven't said what it is that you want your XPath to achieve. This is also usually a good idea, too.
